# how to customize marker in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, marker

I'm new to mapbox and need help about customizing the marker.

I have uploaded a csv file to my map through omnivore
using this code: 
`omnivore.csv('LL62AP0720.csv')
.addTo(map);`

The csv contains 600 records.

How can I customize the marker to my own image? 
I created the marker image in photoshop and how can I apply it to the map?

Thanks!

I tried writing these code:

```
omnivore.csv('LL62AP0720.csv')
.on('ready',function(layer) {  
this.eachLayer(function(marker){
marker.setIcon(L.mapbox.marker.icon({
'marker-color':'#ff8888',
}));
});
```

Is there a way to import the local image to the marker? I think I should add something after the 'marker-color' code, but I don't know what is the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, see this [example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-marker/)

```
 marker.setIcon(L.icon({
            "iconUrl": "/imageURL",
            "iconSize": [100, 100],
            "iconAnchor": [50, 50],
            "popupAnchor": [0, -55],
            "className": "dot"
        }));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also tried to upload the csv to mapbox, and load the markers to the map with the map id. Is there a way to customize these markers?

Answer (score 0):

Use some external library, which could enable you to write HTML/CSS/JavaScript to  fully customized marker just like implementing other parts of the page, like one navbar.

http://easysublease.org/mapcoverjs/